# Правильная реализация перехода по ссылке в рамках одного сайта

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js

Добрый день! 
Есть (точнее будет) магазин. В нем есть ссылки на категории товаров ("для мужчин", "для женщин" и т.п.). Требуется: чтобы после клика по категории открывалась новая страница (с перезагрузкой), где в теле страницы будут выведены товары соответствующей категории. 
Делаю это первый раз, поэтому не знаю как правильнее все организовать. Создавать кучу страниц под каждую категорию товара что-то не сильно хочется, поэтому придумал такую схему:
в  тег `<a>` указать ссылку с идентификатором категории

```
  html
    <a href="category.html?10></a>
```

После клика, сервер (тоже я пытаюсь делать) выдаст страницу category.html

Скрипт на этой странице будет анализировать url, через window.location.search, а потом делать соответствующий AJAX запрос на сервер.

Можно ли закидать меня камнями за такую схему? Если да, то как сделать лучше? Хотя бы схематично. Сервер - NodeJs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сразу нарисовать страницу с нужным содержимым.
Для этого существуют специальные "[шаблонизаторы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)".
Например - [pugjs](https://github.com/pugjs/pug).
Все сводится к тому, что вы в отдельном файле описываете правила, по которым должна строиться ваша страница - с использованием переменных, циклов, условий и потом рендерите страницу, передавая входные данные в ваш шаблон.

Если используете [Express](http://expressjs.com/), в [документации](http://expressjs.com/ru/guide/using-template-engines.html)  есть пример как раз с Pug. Вам нужно будет описать примерно такие маршруты:

```
app.get('/сategory/female', function (req, res) {
  res.render('сategory', {
     type: 'female',
     items: [...]
  });
});

app.get('/сategory/male', function (req, res) {
  res.render('сategory', {
     type: 'male',
     items: [...]
  });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
Я предполагал, что именно в эту сторону нужно "копать".
Буду учить шаблонизацию.

Answer (score 1):

## Готовые решения

Хватит изобретать велосипеды для инвалидов (с костылями), воспользуйтесь готовыми [движками](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA) интернет магазинов - их вполне хватает разного вида, сорта, цвета и вкуса:

- [open cart](https://www.opencart.com)
- [presta shop](https://www.prestashop.com/en)
- [bitrix](https://www.1c-bitrix.ru)
- [magento](https://magento.com)
- [shopify](https://ru.shopify.com)
- [WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com)

Да, это **PHP**, но если у вас нет ярой необходимости поддерживать реайлтайм логику и информация не бегает туда сюда, как, допустим, в играх, то необходимости в **NodeJS** не вижу. **PHP** отлично справляется с запрос-ответ и даже лучше (если сравнивать последние версии) чем **NodeJS**.

Если же у вас стоит такое ТЗ, что предполагает отсутсвие движка и необходима 100% реализация на NodeJS, то добро пожаловать под кат.

---

## Создание с нуля

#### [ЧПУ (человеку понятный URL)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_URL)

Организуйте ссылки аля `/products/for-women/coats/`. Они хорошо распознаются в гуглах и яндексах. Прописывать вручную не надо каждый путь. Укажите один общий с параметрами в URL (прим: `/user/:id`) и, используя параметры, доставайте из БД данные о наличие той или иной (под)категории.

Всё. Это всё. О том как подгружать страницы (ajax / redirect), пользоваться ли серверным рендерингом и т.д. - <s>на ваше усмотрение</s> смотрите в ТЗ.

## GLHF